# QoS Allied Telesis

Tags: networking

I am enabling QoS in my network, i am using Allied Telesis switches, 8000S and X900 for the core. I am using VoIP and i need to priorize my voice data, my telephones are able to mark the frames with VLAN tag and CoS tag.
The 8000S switches can handle the CoS mark and the X900 can priorize with the VLAN tag mark.
My configuration is that:
http://pastebin.com/kxTVTnnh

My network map is that:
Tlph--e3,e5:SW_Escritorio:e24--e16:SW_Lab:e11--port1.0.1:X900:port1.0.11--PBX

I can see that the X900 mark the traffic correctly looking for the VLAN tag, i think that the 8000S are not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see that the x900 has transmitted the frames with the tag you expect?

Did you verify that with a packet capture? You can mirror the egress port easily with the x900.

"i think that the 8000S are not working correctly"

Exactly what do you expect the 800S to do? You can only measure the success of COS tags by oversubscribing the switchport and then measuring which traffic comes out.

Furthermore, the COS tag is carried in the VLAN header. That means that you need to send the traffic from the x900 to the 800S by a tagged ("trunked") VLAN. Then the x900 can put in the COS information.

Comment: First thank you for your answer Michael My problem was solved, i was limiting the traffic between two 8000S with the rate-limit command, i have to use the traffic-shape command, in that way the priorities using the CoS mark is respected. With the rate-limit command the excess of the traffic was dropped without respecting the priorities.